# Logarithm of negative numbers

Tags: complex-numbers, logarithms

I just read the expansion of $\log(1-x) = -x -\frac{x²}{2} - \frac{x³}{3} ....$ So on letting $x = 2$ couldn't I theoretically calculate $\log(-1)$ .

Comment: It won’t converge

Comment: Try checking the radius of convergence for your series.

Comment: Just as a bit of fun, this works in the alternate world of the 2-adics where the absolute value there does have 2 in the radius of convergence $|2|<1$. There the same identities of logs work to allow us to evaluate it as $0=\log(1)=\log((-1)^2)=2 \log(-1)$. This means the numerator of the partial sums of that series become divisible by arbitrarily large powers of 2 for the more terms you add.